# Flutter Firebase login error but still being logged in?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

#### EDIT: The login functions is somehow called twice, once with the correct credentials and the other time the email and password String are empty.

This weird hack seems to fix it, but I cannot see why the login function is called twice:

```
if (email.isEmpty && password.isEmpty) {
  return;
}
```

I have a weird problem that is caused by Firebase-Auth, I believe. Quick summary of the process:

1. User logs in normally, then authenticates with the `local_auth` package using biometrics
2. If that is successful, the login credentials (email, password) are stored on the device using `FlutterSecureStorage`
3. Then, on every new app startup, the user will be prompted with the `local_auth` and if that is successful, I call the login method with the credentials read from the device.

Here comes the error: I get a FirebaseAutException with the error message: `given String is empty or null`, but then I am being logged in, even though there was an error.

This is the login code:

```
  void login({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      final _result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(),
        password: password.trim(),
      );
      if (_result.user != null) {
        print("HERE1");
        if (!_result.user!.emailVerified) {
          Get.to(() => EmailVerificationScreen());
        }
        if (!await credentialsSaved) {
          Get.to(
            () => BiometricsPage(
              email: email.trim(),
              password: password.trim(),
            ),
          );
        }
        Get.find<UserController>().setUser = await Database().getUser(
          _result.user!.uid,
        );
        loggedIn.value = true;
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print("HERE2");
      Get.snackbar(
        "Error logging in",
        e.message!,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        snackStyle: SnackStyle.FLOATING,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      );
    }
  }
```

The print statements occur in the following order:

1. HERE1
2. HERE2

**EDIT**: After a few tries, I saw that sometimes the print-order was exactly the other way around :/

This is the code I use for retrieving the credentials from the device:

```
void checkLocalBiometrics() async {
    if (await credentialsSaved) {
      var localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
      bool canCheckBiometrics = await localAuth.canCheckBiometrics;
      if (canCheckBiometrics) {
        var didAuthenticate = await localAuth.authenticate(
          localizedReason: "-----------------",
          biometricOnly: true,
          stickyAuth: true,
        );
        if (didAuthenticate) {
          var secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
          var storedEmail = await secureStorage.read(key: "email");
          var storedPassword = await secureStorage.read(key: "password");
          login(email: storedEmail!, password: storedPassword!);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the `credentialsSaved` method:

```
Future<bool> get credentialsSaved async {
    var secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    var storedEmail = await secureStorage.read(key: "email");
    return storedEmail != null;
  }
```

I can guarantee that the result of the `secureStorage.read(...)` is not null since I check that in the `credentialsSaved` method. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Turns out that the LoginButton I was using in my LoginPage has an open issue about functions being called twice. ([rounded_login_button bug](https://github.com/chrisedg87/flutter_rounded_loading_button/issues/16)). Can't believe that that was it all the time..